# Getting registry value using WMI

Tags: powershell, registry, wmi

I'm getting an exception which I can't find documented anywhere. Here is the exception:

> The following exception occurred while retrieving the type name
> hierarchy: "Not found".

The `$inParams` is null as well.
and here is the code I'm using:

```
$endpoint = "someEndpointName"
$connectionOptions = New-Object 'System.Management.ConnectionOptions'

$scope = New-Object 'System.Management.ManagementScope'("\\$endpoint\root\cimv2", $connectionOptions)
$scope.Connect()

$registry = New-Object 'System.Management.ManagementClass'($scope, (New-Object 'System.Management.ManagementPath'("StdRegProv")), $null) 
$registrysType = $registry.GetType().Name
#The line above throws this exception: "The following exception occurred while retrieving the type name hierarchy: "Not found".

$inParams = $registry.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue")
$inParams["hDefKey"] = 2147483650 #this represents HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
$inParams["sSubKeyName"] = "SOFTWARE\Company\EOS Version"
$inParams["sValueName"] = "Build S Version"

$outParams = $registry.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", $inParams, $null)

$buildSVersion = $outParams.Properties["sValueText"].Value.ToString()
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use WMI use something like this (taken from the [Scripting Guy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2009/01/05/hey-scripting-guy-how-do-i-check-which-version-of-windows-powershell-im-using/) blog):

```psh
$endpoint = 'someEndpointName'

$basekey  = [uint32]'0x80000002'
$subkey   = 'SOFTWARE\Company\EOS Version'
$value    = 'Build S Version'

$reg = [wmiclass]"\\$endpoint\root\default:StdRegProv"
$buildSVersion = $reg.GetStringValue($basekey, $subkey, $value).sValue
```

Personally I'd prefer using remote registry access, though:

```psh
$endpoint = 'someEndpointName'

$basekey  = 'LocalMachine'
$subkey   = 'SOFTWARE\Company\EOS Version'
$value    = 'Build S Version'

$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($basekey, $endpoint)
$key = $reg.OpenSubKey($subkey, $true)
$buildSVersion = $key.GetValue($value)
```

Comment: Just remember that many Security Guides disable remote registry. It's a way of compromising a machine, so better use Wmi over WinRM and PS.

Answer (score 0):

don't you over complicate things ? all of these to read a value from registry ? what about someting like that

```
icm -ComputerName $endpoint -ScriptBlock {Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\software\7-zip\ |select path}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either method works, but using the measure-command I found the example that icm was 10 times slower, 0.47 seconds versus 4.8 seconds using ICM.